# Could this be a valid user agent for a mobile device?

Tags: php, android, iphone

I have mobile apps that make a call to PHP scripts. In the PHP script, I can look at the User Agent.

I think there may be some other scripts making bursts of calls to my PHP script because I see calls with a user agent looking like...

**Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.109 Safari/537.36**

Normally I would expect a user agent for Android and iPhone of...

**Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 9; POT-LX1 Build/HUAWEIPOT-L21)**

or

**.../187 CFNetwork/978.0.7 Darwin/18.7.0**

Could there ever be a situation where the first user agent is coming from a valid mobile device?

Comment: Yes. It could be coming from a Windows phone. Remember those?

Comment: The first user agent seems to come from Google Chrome browser 72 running on Windows 7. But as these strings can never be trusted, it is possible it could be anything really, even Android phone.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. The requests would be coming from either an Android app  or from an iPhone (not from the browser on the phone but a HTTP request from within the app, Java or Swift).

Answer (score 0):

This is user agent of device running Chrome on Windows.
And user agent this is just a header so you can easily edit it and do request from mobile device with any user agent.

Comment: Would a normal Android or iPhone app send such a user agent considering the call is made from Java or Swift http requests, not from the browser on the phone?